# How to check for failing command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to check via bash script if kubernetes is installed. If it is not I start my setup routine.
I think it would be best to check if `kubectl cluster-info` has an output at all. How do I check for a failing command?

```
if command kubectl cluster-info > /dev/null; then
    # sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"
    # ...
fi
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the command itself has been installed, or that it returns some form of error status?

Comment: Why not run your bash script via [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)? That's what it's built for and it'll setup it up because kubernetes isn't install, not because your `$PATH` was set up incorrectly etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `sh` and compatible shells the exit status from a nonexistent command should be `127`.

> If a command is not found, the exit status shall be `127`. If the command name is found, but it is not an executable utility, the exit status shall be `126`.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02))</sup>

The `command` builtin doesn't change much:

> […] the following exit values shall be returned:
>
> `126`
> The utility specified […] was found but could not be invoked.
>
> `127`
> An error occurred in the command utility or the utility specified […] could not be found.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22_14))</sup>

Your example modified:

```
command kubectl cluster-info >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -eq 127 ]; then …
```

---

There's also `type`.

> The `type` utility shall indicate how each argument would be interpreted if used as a command name.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html))</sup>

POSIX does not specify the exact format of the output. The exit status is only required to tell apart error from success. It's not clear if it's a success to successfully find out the command provided does not exist.

However [in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) there is no doubt:

> The return status is zero if all of the names are found, non-zero if any are not found.

There are useful options:

> If the `-t` option is used, `type` prints a single word which is one of `alias`, `function`, `builtin`, `file` or `keyword`, if name is an alias, shell function, shell builtin, disk file, or shell reserved word, respectively. If the name is not found, then nothing is printed, and `type` returns a failure status.
>
> If the `-p` option is used, type either returns the name of the disk file that would be executed, or nothing if `-t` would not return `file`.

By checking the output and exit status from `type -t kubectl` and/or `type -p kubectl`, you can tell something about `kubectl` *without* invoking it.

Still, finding out in advance that `kubectl`, when used as a command, would be interpreted as a file to run doesn't mean it's *the* `kubectl` you need.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it should be sufficient to do `if command type -p kubectl > /dev/null; then` because if it is not installed, there is no output and if it is installed I do get `/usr/bin/kubectl`, right?

Comment: If you're just wanting to check for the presence of the command,  that's just `[ -x /usr/bin/kubectl ]`

Comment: @roaima True. I would start with it if the OP actually used *full* path to `kubectl`.

Comment: @user3142695 `if` depends on the exit status, not on the output (note you're redirecting output to `/dev/null` anyway). But yes, `if type kubectl >/dev/null; then …` or `if ! type kubectl >/dev/null; then …` is quite sane code in Bash.

Comment: All of these specifically check if it is installed to a directory on your path. Fundamentally, checking if it is installed *anywhere* is a job for your package manager.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers were close to what I needed, but for me the following worked after putting all the existing answers here together:

```
if type kubectl &> /dev/null; then
  source <(kubectl completion bash)
fi
```

Without the ampersand the output still showed in the terminal.